# Which CSS selector is faster?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Which selector is faster: `input[type='text']` or `[type='text']`?

In jQuery the second one but in CSS?

I think that still `[type='sth']` because is "less specific and shorter to read" by browser.

Comment: Talk about micro optimisation...

Comment: Could one measure the difference? On what kind of document – how many elements would it need (matching and/or non-matching) do make a measurable difference? I suppose one might speculate that including both element type and attribute gives more specificity (certainly in the DOM it is easier to check the element type, but does the CSS engine use the DOM?). As @ɴᴀᴛʜ says: unless you can measure the difference in realistic documents focus on clarity of your code.

Comment: My question was theoretical only... :) I know that modern browsers interpret CSS fast and there is no really performance boost between input[type='text'] and type['text'].
I've read this article: [link](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/). 
In short, it said that page renders faster if selectors are less specific (depends of their kind, of course). So, I'd like to know which selector is faster, because input[type='text'] is more specific than the second one.

Comment: in modern browser, css usually not the first thing you need to worry about..SQL query or javascript should be well written then follow by css..just my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS performance check](http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/)
It depends on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Both are faster, the difference is that `[type='sth']` will be applied to all elements including non-input tags.

```
 <link type="sth">
```

This tag will be applied with your class.

Comment: Both are faster than what? I understand the OP to be asking which of the two examples is the faster one.

Comment: Both of them have the same speed. If he needs to load CSS files faster he can minimize them, but browser renders as the same speed both examples that OP are asking.

Comment: then you may wish to edit your answer such that it does not include the statement I queried. The question does not ask about rendering speed. It asks about speed of the selector - selectors are used for more than just styling elements, in preparation for display. ;)

Comment: I think you're mistaken. The OP is asking for browser's render speed when this selector is applied. However, the question is poor and bad writting.

Comment: I'm perfectly confident that I'm not. I welcome evidence to the contrary. Please quote the part of the question that even mentions render-speed. If you've not noticed it, mention of `jQuery` is the hint that the selectors are used for locating an element, rather than rendering it.

Comment: See the tags of the op. Javascript and jQuery is not included. Only CSS. Stop trolling me please. This is that the OP is asking: `because is "less specific and shorter to read" by browser.`

Answer (score 0):

This question is pointless - the answer would have to include a specific version of a specific browser, a specific HTML file, specific css file, specific Javascript and the exact scenario. Also, you would have to define "faster": faster to parse? faster to query from the document? faster to guess if a specific tag fits the rule?

Years ago, when browsers were simple, such made some sense. Modern browsers have optimizations that rival those of modern databases or compilers, and this makes microbenchmarking a moot point. There could be any number of fast paths, exceptions, corner cases, shortcuts for common cases that make such simple reasoning impossible.

Comment: Good text, but it isn't an answers, it is a comment.

Comment: I voted to close the question anyway... and my rant did not fit into comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, there is no way to detect which one is faster, but you can know which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity